# HTML Time line based List style using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want make HTML-CSS Time line with `ul`. I tried to set margins but It's not worked well.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Card View</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="histry-list">
        <li>2016</li>s
        <li>Some top heading</li>
        <li>Sub text</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.histry-list{

   margin-top: 14px;
}

.histry-list li{

    list-style: none;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.histry-list li:first-child{

   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: larger;

   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.histry-list li:last-child{

   font-style: italic;
   color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

[View of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdiAf.jpg)

But I want to design the list like this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXKVh.jpg)

This is one list, but in original project It'll be more than 100. The main goal is to minimize the bandwidth[simply using java script later for printing list] of HTML data.

How can I make it work? Thank you all.

Comment: you can use flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `flex-layout` from `ul` tag

```css
.histry-list{

   margin-top: 14px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.histry-list li{

    list-style: none;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.histry-list li:first-child{

   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: larger;

   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.histry-list li p:last-child{

   font-style: italic;
   color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
   font-size: 14px;
}
.histry-list li p
{
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Card View</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="histry-list">
        <li>2016</li>
        <li>
        <p>Some top heading</p>
        <p>Sub text</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding a few lines as comments or probably as a part of the answer would help in the better understanding of the answer.

Comment: Awesome, I understood clearly. Thank you so much for your help...

Answer (score 2):

```css
.histry-list{

   margin-top: 14px;
}

.histry-list li{

    list-style: none;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 16px;
}


.list-node{
  display:flex;
   color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  font-weight:bold;
   font-size: larger;
}
.year-node{
  padding:15px 10px;
}
.details-node p{
  padding:0px;
  margin:3px;
  font-weight: normal;
   font-size: larger;
   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.details-node p:last-child{
  padding:0px;
  margin:3px;
  font-weight:normal;
   font-size: small;
 font-style: italic;
   color: #9b9b9b;
     font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Card View</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="histry-list">
        <li>
          <div class="list-node">
             <div class="year-node">2016</div>
            <div class="details-node">
              <p>Some top heading</p>
              <p>Sub text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </li>
        
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding a few lines as comments or probably as a part of the answer would help in the better understanding of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer & time that you've spent to answer this post. But I prefer Nethra's answer seems more portable. Because My main goal is to reduce bandwidth.